# He was elected president. VS He was elected as president

Tags: grammar

> He was elected president.
>
> He was elected as president.

Which one is better to teach English language learners?
What would you tell them is the difference between the two?

Why add **as** before president?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would add the *as* to specify the office he was elected to. This would be unnecessary if you were talking about the President of the United States, but might be called for in other cases. For example, if you were listing other offices at the time:

> He was elected as Chief Dogcatcher in 2012 and as Chairman of the Board in 2016.

But you wouldn't need even it in that case. It does no harm, but it is an extra word.

Answer (score -1):

It is better so say:

> He was elected president.

I would add *"as"* only in a specific context, for instance:

> He was elected **as** president **of** the United States of America.